# How to create a custom textinput with dashed borderbottom for the content?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to create a dashed border for the input of my `TextInput` in react-native. Like this http://uupload.ir/files/v9mn_dads.png

So far this is my code:

```
<TextInput maxLength={5} keyboardType={'numeric'} style={styles.numBox}></TextInput>
```

And stylesheetz:

```
  numBox: {
    display: 'flex',
    width: 270,
    height: 58,
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
    marginTop: 50,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile_Bold',
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#CD0448',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor: '#CD0448',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingTop: 15,
  },
});
```

I only manage to create the box and the don't know how to tackle the content dashed issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-confirmation-code-field) package. I guess if you use a `monospace` font, you can achieve this by defining a proper font styles.